# How to create RadioField with a Field as a possible value?

Tags: flask, radio-button, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am using Flask WTForms would like to make a `RadioField` with some simple pre-defined choices, and then a custom choice where the user can input their own string, like so:

- option 1
- option 2
- custom: `<StringField>`

How can I do this?

Comment: What are you tried? Could you add some example to the question? You can implement this with `QuerySelectField` + `StringField` + `ajax`

Comment: example:
What fruit do you like?
    o apples
    o oranges
    o custom (please specify): <type some fruit in this TextField>
I wish not to use ajax if possible.

Comment: You need 1 `Form` with 1 `RadioField` and 1 `TextField`.  Could you explain the problem?

Comment: problem: `RadioField` can only contain strings as possible choices (in fact a tuple of strings). A `TextField` is not a string, because it is a Field. If you know a workaround, that'd be great.

Comment: Could you add your endpoint with Form and template to the question?

Comment: I do not understand your request, could you please rephrase it? I do not know what you mean by "endpoint" in this context.

Comment: I mean your route(for GET and POST processing), form initialization, template etc...

Comment: I'm afraid this is all going to take too much time. Thanks anyway for your considerations, @DanilaGanchar